# Perl CSV removing lines that appear only once

Tags: perl, csv

Hi experts and kind helpers,

I'm new to Perl and I could use some help here. I'm dealing with a CSV file that has more than 1000 lines, but I've replicated and simplified my issue in my example here.

Basically, I want to remove some lines, based on weather or not the second column of the line repeats. I know this might sound confusing, allow me to demonstrate with an example.

Input Data:

```
M,100,John,10
M,98,Mike,9
F,99,Amelia,9
F,100,Rosana,10
F,100,Susan,11
M,99,James,8
```

Expected Output:

```
M,100,John,10
F,100,Rosana,10
F,100,Susan,11
F,99,Amelia,9
M,99,James,8
```

In the example above, Mike is the only one who doesn't share his score (the second column, 98) with the rest of the students, and thus, his name should not be printed. In other words, if the value in the second column of a particular entry is unique/not-repeating in any other entries, then it should be left out. Sorting is optional.

This is what I have so far.

```
use Text::CSV;
use strict;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
my $sheet;

while( <DATA> ) {
  chomp;
  my $row;
  @$row = split( /,/, $_ );
  push @$sheet, $row;
}

@$sheet = sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] } @$sheet;

 foreach my $row ( @$sheet ) {
    print join( ',', @$row), "\n";
}

__DATA__
M,100,John,10
M,98,Mike,9
F,99,Amelia,9
F,100,Rosana,10
F,100,Susan,11
M,99,James,8
```

I'm not even sure where to begin with. Any help/suggestions is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a hash to associate the rows with the value of their second column. In the second step, I would filter out all keys who have only one associated row:

```
my %rows;

while (...) {
  ...;
  push @{ $rows{$row->[1]} }, $row;
}

# After the loop, we filter the keys (and sort them):

my @keys = sort {$b <=> $a} grep { @{$rows{$_}} > 1 }  keys %rows;

# Then print them:

for my $key (@keys) {
  for my $row (@{ $rows{$key} }) {
    # print the @$row
  }
}
```

However, you should actually use `Text::CSV` instead of `split`:

```
my $fh = \*DATA; # or open $fh to a file
while(my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
  push ...;
}
```

and

```
for my $key (@keys) {
  for my $row (@{ $rows{$key} }) {
    $csv->print(\*STDOUT, $row);
  }
}
```

Comment: That is spot on! Thanks a lot amon, exactly what I was looking for :)